# Sorting elements with the same class but different content inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming this structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="box">
        <h1>title1</h1>
        <h3 class="price">5</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="box">
        <h1>title2</h1>
        <h3 class="price">1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="box">
        <h1>title3</h1>
        <h3 class="price">3</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I sort the elements with the class .sortable to show in ascending/descending order based on the class .price inside of the divs? It should happen when clicking a button.

I know that with arrays I could use the .sort method, but as this is not an array, I don't really know how to approach this.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate. The only real difference is that you'll need to get the `.price`'s value instead of the `<option>`'s value, and use `appendChild` instead of creating a `new Option` - if you re-append the children of an element in the order you want, the result is a sorted set of elements.

Comment: Thank you, I was researching before but it seems I didn't use the right words as I didn't find that thread, I'll take a look now!